# “user.mime_type” in desktop environment

Tags: nautilus, desktop-environments, xdg

### Context

[Guidelines for extended attributes (FreeDesktop)](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/CommonExtendedAttributes/) says:

> user.mime_type: Sets the MIME type of a file explicitly. This attribute is documented by the "Shared MIME-info Database Specification".

Then later it says support of this extended attribute is optional. As far as I've tested, this attribute seems to be neither used by the `xdg-mime` command nor by the Nautilus files explorer.

### Question

Is there an option to make either `xdg-mime` or Nautilus (I guess Nautilus relies on `xdg-mime`, so mostly the former) uses the `user.mime_type` extended attribute? If not, is this planned for the future?